# how to read post Json data response from callback url in blazor webassembly?

Tags: c#, blazor, callbackurl

After Payment is completed by user whether it is failed or success payment gateway provider will send data with call back url in the form of Json as Post data. I want to read that Post data in blazor can any one please help me to find out the solution?

Comment: Blazor Server or WASM?

Comment: In Blazor WASM.

Comment: Think you're going to have to get the server you download the app from to help you out for this one.. describe the process you're going through in full